# VBA converting copy/paste to value = value causes error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a bunch of copy/paste of cell ranges into a more simple (and apparently faster) value = value style.

essentially I am going from this,

```
wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(vaLastRow, i)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strWorkingTableName).Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

to this,

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strWorkingTableName).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells((1 + vaLastRow - 5), 1)).Value = wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(vaLastRow, i)).Value
```

but when I do I get the dreaded "Run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object defined error".

Please help me in figuring out why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I hate that error. It's so generic.

Comment: The range sizes mismatch. You're assigning from something that has `vaLastRow - 4` rows into something that has `vaLastRow - 5` rows (I think - it's getting late and math is getting hard)

Comment: @Mikegrann if I replace it with
    vaLastRow - 5
or
    vaLastRow - 4

is still comes up with the same error.

Comment: value of `vaLastRow` is < 5 or value  `i` is <1 or both.

Comment: Or, worksheet is protected. But most likely it's an invalid range definition.

Comment: @cyboashu vaLastRow can't be < 5 (the code where I obtain the value starts at row 6), and i starts at 1. Also, the original code I show works fine.

Comment: @DavidZemens Ah, didn't realize that could be an issue, I'll check. What do you mean by invalid range definition?

Comment: Unqualified reference to Cells object. You're defining a range on 2 sheets, using the Cells object which is implicitly the Activesheet. Since a range can't span multiple sheets, one or both sides of your assignment statement is raising the error.

Comment: @DavidZemens got it, didn't realize that about the Cells object. thanks!

Comment: @tincanfury it's a super-common error, no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
with wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(vaLastRow, i))
    thisworkbook.sheets(strWorkingTableName).cells(2,1).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count).value = .value
end with
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it thinks you are trying to create some sort of object with the `=`.

I would maybe try something like this:

```
newvalue = wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(vaLastRow, i)).Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strWorkingTableName).Range("your range").Value = newvalue
```

I believe you can also do something like this:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("sheetname1").Range("your range").Copy wb1.Sheets("sheetname2").Range("your range")
```

Comment: *I believe it thinks you are trying to create some sort of object with the =* Nope, that would raise a different error (438, probably). This is a valid way of "copying" a range of values to another location